# Python and ZeroMQ subscriber acknowledgement to publisher

Tags: python, zeromq

I am trying to get an acknowledgement from my subscriber back to my publisher using ZeroMQ in Python.

I tried a few code examples, using a `zmq.PUSH` and `zmq.PULL` code sequence, but to no avail.

My code as it stands:

**`PUB_SERVER.PY`**

```
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

port = "5556"
if len( sys.argv ) > 1:
   port =  sys.argv[1]
   int( port )

   context = zmq.Context()
   socket  = context.socket( zmq.PUB )
   socket.bind( "tcp://*:%s" % port )

   while True:
      # topic = random.randrange( 9999, 10005 )
      topic       = 10000
      messagedata = random.randrange( 1, 215 ) - 80
      print        "%d %d" % ( topic, messagedata )
      socket.send( "%d %d" % ( topic, messagedata ) )
      time.sleep( 1 )
```

**`SUB_CLIENT.PY`**

```
import sys
import zmq

port = "5556"
if len( sys.argv ) > 1:
   port =  sys.argv[1]
   int( port )

   if len( sys.argv ) > 2:
      port1   =  sys.argv[2]
      int( port1 )

      # Socket to talk to server
      context = zmq.Context()
      socket  = context.socket( zmq.SUB )

      print "Collecting updates from weather server..."
      socket.connect( "tcp://192.168.0.21:%s" % port )

if len( sys.argv ) > 2:
   socket.connect(    "tcp://192.168.0.21:%s" % port1 )

   # Subscribe to zipcode, default is NYC, 10001
   topicfilter = "10000"
   socket.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topicfilter )

   # Process 5 updates
   total_value = 0
   for update_nbr in range( 5 ):
      string = socket.recv()
      topic, messagedata = string.split()
      total_value += int( messagedata )
      print topic, messagedata

   print "Average messagedata value for topic '%s' was %dF" % ( topicfilter, total_value / update_nbr )
```

That code gives me the output of the server in one SSH window (on a Parallella), and the received filtered messages of the client in another SSH window (on a RaspberryPi) which is working great.

Where I am lost is, once the client has gotten a filtered message from the server, **how would it acknowledge** that filtered message being received, and then have the server log those acknowledged messages?

Eventually, I'd want to do some intelligent decision making of sending a file to the subscriber who acknowledges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to acknowledge?

May create a parallel messaging structure for a soft-signalling for that purpose.

Extend **`PUB_SERVER.PY`** with a **`.SUB`** Rx access point:

```
anAckRxSOCKET  = context.socket( zmq.SUB )               # create SUB side
anAckRxSOCKET.bind( "tcp://*:%s" % aServerAckPORT ) )    # .bind()
anAckRxSOCKET.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "" )            # SUB to *-anything
# ...
anAckRxSTRING = anAckRxSOCKET.recv()                     # .recv()
```

Extend **`SUB_CLIENT.PY`** with a **`.PUB`** Tx socket to the Server side access point:

```
anAckTxSOCKET  = context.socket( zmq.PUB )               # create PUB side(s)
anAckTxSOCKET.connect( "tcp://192.168.0.21:%s" % aServerAckPORT ) )
```

and
send ACK(s) with "*a-proxy-ID*" for any server-side processing you may want or need

```
anAckTxSOCKET.send( topicfilter )                        # ACK with an "identity"-proxy
```

Comment: I'll give that a run tomorrow!

Comment: Hi, I just gave that a run, here are my results:

- from client
Collecting updates from weather server...
10000 -69
10000 63
10000 -22
10000 -64
10000 81
Average messagedata value for topic '10000' was -3F 

- from server (acknowledgement)

63
-22
-22
-64
-64 

My first bits of data are chopped off, and following bits are duplicated. Any ideas?